# Swift Package Manager - Speech dependency not loading

Tags: swift, swift4, swift4.2, swift-package-manager

I'm encountering an issue creating a Swift Package for my project. I have CocoaPods and Travis CI running and both are working swimmingly, however I now intend to also offer the project through the Swift Package Manager. This is where I'm running into issues. My package file is looking like the following:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Voxosonus",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Voxosonus",
            targets: ["Voxosonus"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "Voxosonus",
            path: "Voxosonus"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "VoxosonusTests",
            dependencies: ["Voxosonus"],
            path: "VoxosonusTests"),
    ]
)
```

However when I run `swift build` I encounter the following:

```
/Users/<hidden>/Documents/Projecten/Voxosonus/Voxosonus/SpeechRecognizer.swift:8:8: error: no such module 'Speech'
import Speech
```

My question is - why is it unable to find the 'Speech' module? This is core functionality from Apple themselves and so far the internet has made me none the wiser. Some details on the project:

Build target: iOS 12.x

macOS: 10.14

Swift Version: 4.2.1

Comment: Maybe the `Voxosonus` package isnt written in Swift 4.2..

Comment: Except it is because if not the Travis CI build and the CocoaPods would not work - which they do. Also in the Voxosonus.xcodeproj file, the swift compiler is set to version 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Swift Package Manager Github](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#depending-on-apple-modules), you can't define the target platform of a *Swift Package* yet:

> At this time there is no explicit support for depending on UIKit,
>   AppKit, etc, though importing these modules should work if they are
>   present in the proper system location. We will add explicit support
>   for system dependencies in the future. Note that at this time the
>   Package Manager has no support for iOS, watchOS, or tvOS platforms.

So when you are try to build the library with *Xcode* (or with the `swift build` command), the compiler can't find the *Speech* module because it is only available on iOS 10+.

You can check this [github project](https://github.com/j-channings/swift-package-manager-ios) (swift-package-manager-ios) which provides a ruby script that modify the `xcodeproj` generated by the *Swift Package Manager* by adding the necessary information in order to build for the iOS platform.

Comment: Thank you - I'll have a look at this solution, although it seems to me that with that information, the Swift Package Manager and it's support is something that can wait for the foreseeing future if this is the case so I'll leave it be for now.

Comment: Yes for the moment SPM is mainly designed for the Linux support. I hope it'll support iOS in the next version...